# "bash: pip: command not found" when using "pip install ..."

Tags: python, bash, pip

On Linux Ubuntu with python 3.6.9

When i try to download pip, it says i already have it. So when i try to pip install ... it gives me error "bash: pip: command not found".

When i type "which pip" in the terminal it gives me nothing and creates a new line.

(While also it doesn't work in the normal terminal) I should also say I'm trying to do this in a virualenv. It gives the same errors when  trying to install pip (I already have it) and when trying to use pip ("bash: pip: command not found")

echo $PATH output: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

*sorry if this doesn't make sense, kinda a noob*

Comment: Sounds like bash doesn’t know where to find pip.  Might need to be added to your env variables. Please update your question with the output of `echo $PATH`, from your venv.

Comment: Have you tried `python3 -m pip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

- `python -m pip install ....`
- `python3 -m pip install ....`
- `py3 -m pip install ....`

As @S3DEV commented, there could be a problem with your path variables, so trying `python` before `pip` could solve. Those other variations (`python3` and `py`) can also work.

Comment: python3 -m pip install .... has allowed me to install the package, but is there a way so i can get pip commands to work. Even things like pip list, etc. wont even work

Comment: You can do `python3 -m pip list`. Also, check on how to configure the pip path on your Ubuntu.